# Go back to previous Div upon clicking link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that brings back the previous div shown but it won't work. a helping hand would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
    $("#prev-link").click(function () {
        $("#div-a").fadeOut();
        $("#first-div").fadeIn();
        return false;
    });

     $("#prev-link").click(function () {
        $("#div-b").fadeOut();
        $("#first-div").fadeIn();
        return false;
    });

     $("#prev-link").click(function () {
        $("#div-c").fadeOut();
        $("#first-div").fadeIn();
        return false;
    });

     $("#prev-link").click(function () {
        $("#div-d").fadeOut();
        $("#first-div").fadeIn();
        return false;
    });

     $("#prev-link").click(function () {
        $("#div-e").fadeOut();
        $("#first-div").fadeIn();
        return false;
    });

     $("#prev-link").click(function () {
        $("#div-f").fadeOut();
        $("#first-div").fadeIn();
        return false;
    });

     $("#prev-link").click(function () {
        $("#div-g").fadeOut();
        $("#first-div").fadeIn();
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

---

So basically "#first-div" is a pop up modal menu div that contains links to divs a ~ g, what I want to happen is upon clicking the "#prev-link" (which is a link located at the button left corner of divs a ~ g.) the div which is currently shown (could be a/b/c/d/e/f/g or which ever the user clicked) would fadeout and show the menu div which is the "#first-div".

NOTE: #first-div is a pop up modal so is divs a ~ g

fiddle: `http://jsfiddle.net/8Py7W/4/`

Comment: can you share the html??

Comment: this is wrong: ``$(#div-a, #div-b, #div-c, #div-d, #div-e, #div-f, #div-g)``

Comment: Give all those divs a class name (same name) and onclick of that class just fade `$(this).fadeOut();` and `$("#first-div").fadeIn();`

Comment: I updated the post, hopefully you guys get the idea.

Comment: Try this - [http://jsfiddle.net/8Py7W/9/](http://jsfiddle.net/8Py7W/9/) fiddle. Do let us know if this is not the intended logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
<div id="first-div" class="popup-box">
<ul class="links">
      <li><a href="#div-a" class="login-window">A Content</a></li>
      <li><a href="#div-b" class="login-window">B Content</a></li>
       <li><a href="#div-c" class="login-window">C Content</a></li>
      <li><a href="#div-d" class="login-window">D Content</a></li>
       <li><a href="#div-e" class="login-window">E Content</a></li>
      <li><a href="#div-f" class="login-window">F Content</a></li>
      <li><a href="#div-g" class="login-window">G Content</a></li>
</ul>    
<a href="" class="close" id="close"></a>
</div>
<!--------------------------------------->

<div class="divclass popup-box" id="div-a">
 <a href="" class="close" id="close"></a>
 <a href="#first-div"><div  class="center_content_view_all" id="prev-link">&lt;&lt;prev</div></a>  
</div>
<!------------------------------->
<div class="divclass popup-box" id="div-b">
 <a href="" class="close" id="close"></a>
  <a href="#first-div"><div  class="center_content_view_all" id="prev-link">&lt;&lt;prev</div></a>  
</div>
<!------------------------------->
<div class="divclass popup-box" id="div-c">
 <a href="" class="close" id="close"></a>
 <a href="#first-div"><div  class="center_content_view_all" id="prev-link">&lt;&lt;prev</div></a>  
</div>
<!------------------------------->
<div class="divclass popup-box" id="div-d">
 <a href="" class="close" id="close"></a>
 <a href="#first-div"><div  class="center_content_view_all" id="prev-link">&lt;&lt;prev</div></a>  
</div>
<!------------------------------->
<div class="divclass popup-box" id="div-e">
 <a href="" class="close" id="close"></a>
  <a href="#first-div"><div  class="center_content_view_all" id="prev-link">&lt;&lt;prev</div></a>  
</div>
<!------------------------------->
<div class="divclass popup-box" id="div-f">
 <a href="" class="close" id="close"></a>
  <a href="#first-div"><div  class="center_content_view_all" id="prev-link">&lt;&lt;prev</div></a>  
</div>
<!------------------------------->
<div class="divclass popup-box" id="div-g">
 <a href="" class="close" id="close"></a>
  <a href="#first-div"><div  class="center_content_view_all" id="prev-link">&lt;&lt;prev</div></a>  
</div>

$(function () {
    $('.divclass').hide();

    $('#first-div').show();

    $('.login-window').on('click', function() {
        $('#first-div').hide();
        $($(this).attr('href')).show();
    });

    $(".center_content_view_all").click(function () {
        $(".divclass").fadeOut();
        $("#first-div").fadeIn();
        return false;
    });
});`
```